# Android cordova plugin with callback

Tags: java, android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am converting a IOS phonegap plugin to android. In IOS there is a plugin call like this

```
cordova.exec('InAppPurchaseManager.requestProductsData', callbackName, {productIds: productIds});
```

This line of code is using the native layer to fetch the product details from itues store. Once this message is send to native layer it then makes an asynchronous request to get products details.Once it has the products it then makes the call

```
NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.apply(plugins.inAppPurchaseManager, %@);", callback, [callbackArgs cdvjk_JSONSerialize]];
    [command writeJavascript: js];
```

In above line the variable callback holds the value passed by the argument **callbackName** when the plugin is invoked. How can I do the same in android?

The plugin dont have an option to recieve the callbackname value in android

```
public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException
```

In android from phonegap I am using this method

```
cordova.exec(callbackName, null, "MyPluginClass", "getProducts", productIds);
```

How can I implement the same in android?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Google Play Stores In App Billing service.  This project on GitHub has some good examples:

https://github.com/poiuytrez/AndroidInAppBilling

I didn't get time to create one code base myself for both IOS and Android but I plan to in the future...  What I ended up doing is the following, it probably would have been faster to add a seperate layer but I was just trying to get it to work at the time and will refactor in the future... Here's how I did it which required minimum modification to the Android GitHub project:

```
           if ( window.plugins.InAppPurchasePlugin ) {

            // launch the ios in app purchase MakePurchase function....
            var quantity = 1;

            window.plugins.InAppPurchasePlugin.buyProduct( config.gratitudeIosInAppProductId, quantity, buyProductError );
        }
        else {

            if ( window.plugins.inappbilling ) {

                window.plugins.inappbilling.buy( androidBuySuccessHandler, buyProductError, config.gratitudeAndroidInAppProductId );
            }
            else {

                kendoConsole.log( 'no inappbilling?' );
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. I am using google In ap billing service. But I am trying to reuse the callbacks existing in the current source code of phonegap to avoid more coding. Do you have any idea how the callback parameter can be received in android?